# Account History tracking shows codes instead of full names after enabling State/Country picklists

Tags: picklist, country-and-state

I'm seeing that changes made on an Account after we have enabled State & Country/Territory Picklists on our sandbox default to showing the shortcodes for Country & State.  Isn't it possible to show the full values instead of these shortcodes in the Account history?  Preferable would be 'Changed **Billing Country** from **Netherlands** to **United States of America**.

Here´s what being shown in the Account History list:

[image: Country shortcodes]

And here is the configuration value for Netherlands in the State & Country picklists.  Notice the 'Country/Territory Code'.   Why is that being picked up in the history report?   If no one has encounteered this before it may be a bug.  I haven't enabled this on the production environment yet, so it may be something related to the sandbox and not the implementation per se.

[image: Netherlands]

Answer (score 0):

When you define your picklist values, you decide what you want to allow in the picklist. If you define the state values as abbreviations, that's what the user will see. By default, the State names are configured, but you can add/remove those in the State and Country picklist configuration page under Data Management.

In data Management->State and Country/Territory Picklists

As per my knowledge Standard Country/Territory code you can't able to change.But 
you can raise a case to salesforce.

But,If you create any new Country/Territory codes you have access to change and you need inactivate existing Territory before you create new one.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: See the edited question above.

Comment: Please check my update answer

Comment: Thanks for that Pavan.  The likeliest explanation for this is that this is some bug in the presentation layer  -why would you want to show shortcodes if the full name is available. When I deploy this to live I'll see whether this is also present there.